# MSbuild.exe not adding correct dependency for UWP app targeting .Net Native 1.6

Tags: msbuild, uwp, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore, .net-native

I have a blank UWP app in which I have referred 
"Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.3.2"

Now I expect that after nuget restore and MSbuild I should get these in "Dependencies" folder of the package. Basically it should use .Net Native 1.6 tool chain for compilation.

- Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.6.appx
- Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.6.appx
- Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx

However, I am getting below in the dependencies

- Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.3.appx
- Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.4.appx
- Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx

When I create a package from Visual Studio it works fine.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 professional: 15.1 (26403.7) latest as on today
Nuget.exe: 4.1 (latest as on today)
MSBuild version '15.1.1012.6693'

**Nuget restore command :** 
nuget.exe restore App9\App9.sln -verbosity detailed

**MSBuild path:**
MSBuild.exe" App9\App9\App9.csproj /property:Configuration=Release /p:WarningLevel=0 /property:Platform=x64 /p:OutputPath=x64 /p:AppxBundle=
Always

Sample app (one drive path ): https://1drv.ms/u/s!Agx9OwudY0zliTcOMRxKYtd-N3rU

Comment: I'm using Nuget 4.1 and the result is right as you showed above. The official only provide 4.1 for the newest release. Where you get the Nuget 4.2?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT, you are correct, that was my mistake. I have correct it now in the original question.

Comment: Be sure to look at the [.NETStandard platform support table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library).  "vNext" means "next version, we don't know which and we don't know when".  This is work in progress.

Comment: So did you mean you still have issues with Nuget 4.1?  The dependencies are right on my side with nuget restore command. Could you please provide some relative screenshots? What's your OS version?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I am still having the issues with Nuget 4.1. Although I am not sure if the issue is with Nuget or, MSBuild.exe or makeappx.exe . And this specifically happens only if you are using Project.json for Nuget reference and not PackageReference in .csproj as its there in the sample app (already linked with question)